# Disappearing comments

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

I noticed some of my comments disappearing without me triggering this (at least not that I am aware of). Example: placed a comment in reaction to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/71582/is-it-possible-to-have-a-geostationary-satellite-over-the-poles). It's now gone.

Anyone an idea what is happening?

Comment: Sometimes, though    , this problem maybe disastrous if the OP doesn't bother changing their post (E.g. if it's complete garbage).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comments are meant to be temporary: to solicit clarification or point out potential edits, that sort of thing. So they tend to get deleted. If a comment doesn't really add anything substantial, it's liable to be deleted more quickly.

So basically, if your comments disappear, don't worry, that's just the system working as intended. If you have something to say that is worth preserving, something that you *don't* want to disappear after a while, put it in an answer. (Obviously, it should be something that actually does constitute an answer to the question.)

Comment: It's not really an issue here because meta sites are more discussion-oriented, so we tend not to delete comments so much on meta. (Of course remember that when you want to thank someone for an answer, an upvote and/or accept is sufficient! Generally you don't need to use a comment.)

Comment: So does it happen automatically or it is up to mods? Because my comment in [278472](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/278472/25453) was deleted.  I think it was adding a value to the topic though wasn't worth a separate answer. Was it maybe against some rules?

Comment: @Kuba Comments are not deleted automatically, as far as I know. It's done by the moderators. But the point of my answer was that, even when a comment gets deleted, that doesn't mean it broke any rules. (That _particular_ comment was deleted because it wasn't trying to improve the question. It's preferable if you don't post comments like that, but it's not a big deal.)

Comment: Maybe it wasn't improving the question but it was addressing OP's predictions. It was adding more value to the topic than quite big part of existing comments (just scan top questions). I find the policy of deleting comments without notification, while obviously useless comments are all around, at least annoying.  Won't argue with that anymore, not my fight :) Thanks for info :)

Comment: @Kuba If you see useless comments, flag them and we'll delete them. Most comment deletions come in response to flags. The deletion of comments is part of the SE model: we try to minimize distractions to the questions and answers. So it's something to just get used to if you're going to stick around.

Comment: You are aware that intensity of such actions varies across SE :) I consider that deletion an overreaction but as I said I won't argue, I'm a new guest in physics.se so I don't want to fight with that :)

Comment: @Kuba Oh, of course. This is a frequent topic of discussion among the moderators (of all sites). We tend to think some of the other sites' mods are slackers (this is good-natured ribbing) and place too much value on comments. You'll find many situations where the culture of moderation varies widely from one site to another.